# For a spherically symmetric Riemannian manifold, are all the metric functions even or odd?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, spherical-coordinates, symmetry, even-and-odd-functions

For a spherically symmetric Riemannian manifold, we can write the metric as

$ds^2 = a^2(r)dr^2 + b^2(r)d\Omega^2$

Now I think the metric components have to be even functions for the manifold to be smooth, because if you go through the origin to "negative $r$" you're really just going to positive $r$ on the other side, so you have to hit all the same metric values.

And that implies that $a(r)$ and $b(r)$ (what I'm calling the "metric functions" for lack of a precise term) would all have to be even or odd, right?  I'm especially interested in the tangential function $b(r)$ -- to be smooth, we need $b(0) = 0$ and $b'(0) = 1$ so that it locally looks like Euclidean space, so I guess $b(r)$ has to be odd.  Whereas the radial function, as well as the time function in a Lorentzian manifold, have to be even.

Is that correct?

Comment: By $r$, are you referring to standard polar coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^n$, or an set of coordinates on an arbitrary Riemannian manifold? In the former case, smoothness at the origin results in requirements on the $r\to 0^+$ limits of $a(r)$, $b(r)$, their derivatives, while in the latter case you can't say much of anything about what happens outside of the coordinate patch without a global description of "spherical symmetry".

Comment: @Kajelad  Yes, I mean standard polar coordinates.  So do the requirements that you mention imply those functions are even/odd?

Comment: Neither, strictly speaking. Polar coordinates are only defined for $r>0$, so $a$ and $b$ would have domain $(0,\infty)$.